# Ember triggering property updates on blur

Tags: ember.js

I am using Ember and when I type in text box the binded property on the controller is automatically as I type, I would like to know if there is way to change this only update the property on the blur event?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a temporary property to your input's value and use the focus-out event to update the "real" property:

```
{{input value=tempValue focus-out="updateValue"}}
```

```
actions: {
    updateValue() {
        this.set('realValue', this.get('tempValue'));
    }
}
```